# Can people who own the Necromancer and people who don't play together?

Tags: diablo-iii

My friends have the Diablo 3 Battle Chest version of the game and I want to play as the Necromancer in the Eternal Collection version.

So I was wondering: would I be able to use the character even though the others don't have it?

(Just wanted to make sure so I don't waste my money)

Answer (score 5):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/diablo3/comments/6juhcx/playing_with_a_friend_who_isnt_getting/), yes.
Your friends won't have access to the class, that's about it.

Comment: That steam quote appears to be for a different game.

Comment: I can also confirm this as a player that is playing as Necromancer along with a long time Demon Hunter main friend who (obviously) doesn't own the Necromancer DLC. The only thing player needs to play multi player coop is Reaper of Souls DLC.